# Why does Laravel Controller needs (integer) cast in Homestead, but not in production server

Tags: laravel, casting, controller, integer, homestead

**(integer) cast must be done in Homestead for Controller parameter**

I am having a hard time searching for the cause of a discrepancy between my local dev environment (Homestead) and the hosted one.
I define a route like this:

```
Route::get('group/{id}/data', 'GroupDataController@index');
```

And the code in the Controller looks like this:

```
public function index($id)
{
    return Grouping::all()->where('group_id', $id);
}
```

Which works fine in production (hosted env), BUT when I execute it locally it throws and empty array [] unless I modify my Controller function to look like this:

```
public function index($id)
{
    return Grouping::all()->where('group_id', (integer)$id);
}
```

I have no idea of what is going on in here, and I am tired of making changes all over my Controller to make it work on both environments.
I have searched in several place, but maybe I am using incorrect tokens for my search as I have found nothing.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not using the correct set of functions.

When you call `Grouping::all()`, this is actually returning an Eloquent `Collection` object with every record in your groupings table. You are then calling the `where()` method on this `Collection`. This causes two problems: one, it is horribly inefficient; two, the `where()` method on the `Collection` works differently than the `where()` method on the query builder.

The `where()` method on the `Collection` takes three parameters: the name of the field, the value in that field on which to filter, and finally a boolean value to tell it whether or not to do a strict comparison (===) or a loose comparison (==). The third parameter defaults to strict. This strict comparison is why you're having the issue you are having, but I cannot explain why one environment sees `$id` as an integer and the other doesn't.

The `where()` method on a query builder object will actually add a where clause to the SQL statement being executed, which is a much more efficient way of filtering the data. It also has more flexibility as it is not limited to just equals comparisons (the second parameter is the comparison operator for the where clause, but will default to "=" if it is left out).

You have two options to fix your issue. You can either pass in `false` as the third parameter to your `where()` method in the current code (bad), or you can update the code to actually filter using the query instead of filtering on the entire `Collection` (good).

I would suggest updating your code to this:

```
public function index($id) {
    return Grouping::where('group_id', '=', $id)->get();
}
```

In the above code, `Grouping::where('group_id', '=', $id)` will generate a query builder object that has the given where clause, and then `get()` will execute the query and return the `Collection` of results.

Comment: When I try to implement as suggested, I get:
**Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string**

It seems (even my IDE warns me about it) that my Eloquent model has no access to a where method.

Comment: @iaef Did you make sure to add the call to `->get()`? You would get that error if `->get()` was left off.

Comment: @iaef Explanation for `where()`: The Eloquent model does not actually have a `where()` method. However, it uses the PHP magic `__call()` method to redirect any missing method to an Eloquent query builder. If the Eloquent query builder does not have the method, it uses the `__call()` method to redirect to a Fluent query builder. If the Fluent query builder doesn't have the method, then you would get a `BadMethodCallException`.

Comment: I corrected the difference in coding (needing to cast to integer) by connecting my Homestead server to the production database. Maybe something different in the table definition like collation.

@patricus what you suggested works but I found that if I try to return just some columns, I do not get what I want. Your explanation is clearing things up for me.

I am trying with:
`Application::all(['id', 'test_id', 'schedule_id', 'school_id'])->where('test_id', '=', $id)->get('id');` but I get a blank page, with nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

I marked @patricus (thanks you, so much!) as the correct answer, for he really pointed me in the right direction to understand that there are some keywords that work differently under different contexts (like get()), but I will also point out, how my 2 confusing points were solved in my case:

1. The difference in my code between production and Homestead development environments was solved by pointing my Homestead to the production database. I am not sure what was the difference (maybe collation or table format), but it gave me a quick out.
2. I was trying to filter a list of elements in the database but I was constructing it with the wrong logic for Laravel.

To clear what I refer to in the second point, I was using this code:

```
Grouping::all(['id', 'name_id', 'product_id', 'ship_id'])->where('name_id', '=', $id);
```

I thought this could work, because it would be selecting all items, with the selected columns, and then filter those with a where clause. But I was **wrong**, since, as I found out later, the correct way of writing this is:

```
Grouping::where('name_id', $id)->select('id', 'name_id', 'product_id', 'ship_id')->get();
```

This is because I forgot completely that I was assembling the query, not writing the actions I expected the program to do.
This second syntax has more logic, since I specify the filter, then put the columns over what was filtered, and finally execute the query with the get() clause.

Of course, it can also be written the other side around for clearer fluent reading:

```
Grouping::select('id', 'name_id', 'product_id', 'ship_id')->where('name_id', $id)->get();
```

Comment: With your final code (which looks correct), you should be able to switch your Homestead instance back to the development database, as the code is no longer doing a strict comparison in php, but is sending in the value to the sql query. If your final code still fails in your development environment, then that is very confusing.